# If R is an equivlance relation and is also a function with domain A

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

If R is an equivalence relation on A and is also a function with domain A, Describe R.

$A= \{ 1,2,3,...,n \} $

Im not really sure what this is saying.

1) i know that R is reflexive symmetric and transitive.

However its kind of hard to imagine what f is i mean its taking every element a to (a,a) and whenever it takes a to (a,b) it takes b to (b,a) its like some kind of really messed up Cartesian product.

Worst still i see nothing that f contributes to the situation (other than confusion) which leaves me rather lost to describing R bases on f.

Functions in there most basic form don't need to have well any nice properties they don't have to be 1-1 (this one clearly isnt unless it just takes a to (a,a) only when a=a. they dont have to be onto ( this one clearly isnt unless for all $a,b \in A$  the pair (a,b) is in the range of f. which IS the Cartesian product. but in general functions without at least one of these properties are pretty useless..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding this problem is in understanding the nature of $f$.

First and foremost, a function is a *special relation*. A relation is just a subset of $A \times A$, right?

> A function $f$ is a relation (a subset of $A \times A$ ) such that $\forall a \in A$, there is a *unique* $b \in A$ (which we call $f(a)$) such that $(a,b) \in f$.
>
> An equivalence relation $f$ on $A$ *must satisfy* $(a,a) \in f$ for all $a \in A$, which is the reflexivity property, along with transitivity and symmetry (which aren't important for us here)

Now, if $f$ is a function *and* an equivalence relation, then consider $f(a)$. It must be the *unique* $b \in A$ such that $(a,b) \in f$. However, $(a,a) \in f$ because $f$ is *also* an equivalence relation.

Hence, $f(a) = a$ for all $a$. That is, $f$ is just the *identity* relation, or function on $A$, where $(a,a) \in f$ for all $a$, and no other pairs are present.

Comment: By this, I take it you have understood the answer, including the fact that I merely needed *reflexivity* of  $f$ as a relation, and not any of the other properties for the answer.